# detect post-it from an image of a visual management

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to detect all the post-it in an image and get them into an arrayList.
I tried many alternatives (removing backgroud -> detecting contours, haar Cascade
classifier, detecting rectangular objects...) but none of them gave me good results.
[this is an example of input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29Pz.jpg)
Any Idea how to proceed? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe segment by color and findContours afterwards?

Comment: thanx @Phann i'll try segmentation by color as you said and keep you up-to-date with reesults.